# where to use NSLayoutRelation Less Than Or Equal and NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am creating Layout constraint programatically.
I am little bit confuse those two keyword 1)NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
2)NSLayoutRelation Less Than Or Equal

Please can any one tell me where to use and Why with example if possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's usually use if you want a view to have a constraint that's `>=` some value, normally then it want an `=` value, thats all, example where to use is that you dont want a view that's too close to border, but fine for anything more than 30px for example, so you pin it to border and use `GreaterThanOrEqual` 30, so it wont conflict with anything that change it's width or height